# File download is not working in Azure VM with curl command

Tags: azure, ubuntu, curl

I ran some commands on the Azure VM shell script environment, but the `curl` command seems not working.

```
sudo -i
curl -o cosigner "<<URL Download Link>>"
```

`URL Download Link` format is like this: `https://fb-customers.s3.amazonaws.com/install-script/cosigner-v1.1.5?X-Amz-Algorithm=....LONG_KEY....`

[image]

It's saying `No such file or directory.`
I think the file download is not working.
What is the reason?

Comment: Looks like either you might be using the incorrect URL or the File is not located at the specified destination. Could you try this command on the source machine to see if everything is correct "curl -I<<URL>>"

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below output***

***I have created the Linux VM***

[image]

***I used the below command to run the shell script***

```
az vm run-command invoke -g <RG_name> -n <vm_name> --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y"
```

[image]

*In Linux VM click on RunCommand>click on ShellScript to open the command shell*

***For install/upgrading the curl use the below command***

```
sudo apt install curl/apt-get update -y
```

***To check the curl version***

```
curl --version
```

***I have downloaded the file using below command***

```
curl -O <https://fb-customers.s3.amazonaws.com/install-script/cosigner-v1.1.5?X-Amz-Algorithm=....LONG_KEY....>
```

[image]

***I have saved file and able to see the file content***

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

*1). I am not able to see the content of the file because restrictions from the url*

*2). when I open the file I am able to see the below content that content only displayed as the output*

[image]